# Handsontable : Can't get anything but "undefined" when i run the countRows method

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

Hello everyone :) Thank's for your time,reading my issue. 
I'm using the handsontable library since a week and i have some troubles using a couples of methods.

I have the following code in a function :

```
count = $('#tableur').handsontable('countRows');
```

It appears that count = "undefined" when i try to print it.

My handsontable is build this way :

```
var container1 = document.getElementById('tableur');

var settings1 = {
data: mydata,
// colHeaders: Headers,
minRows: 28,
minCols: 10,
rowHeights: 40,
colWidths: 110,
formulas: true,
cells: function(row, col, prop) {
  var cellProperties = {};
  if ((~rowBigPhase.indexOf(row)) || row === 0) {
    cellProperties.renderer = bigPhasesRender;
  }
  return cellProperties;
},
columns: columns
};

var hot1 = new Handsontable(container1, settings1);
```

I did'nt include in the code the var Headers,mydata,columns, and the part when i get the data  via ajax or the updateSetting and the context menu, because it's useleless of course. But if you need the all code i can give it to you.

If you can actually explain me how to get the method to work or if it's a bug of the library instead, i will be thankfull and you will help me to get through my work in time, i have been stuck on this since 4 hours now !

Thanks you all, hope to get the answer soon :)

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

While you are using ajax to get data so then table is getting rendered again after your ajax call success so before render you would get undefined :) you can use events there for counting rows after ajax update

http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.2/Hooks.html#event:afterChange

Answer (score 1):

Well, if anyone ever comes along asking the same question, use it this way:

`hot1.countRows()`

use JQuery if you initialized the table with JQuery.